# Unable to Generate correct TOTP code from Twilio Authy App Node JS

Tags: node.js, security, npm, totp

Here is the scenrio, Id like to utilize https://npm.io/package/otplib to generate a TOTP code and verify it with the user input. The issue is that I am unable to generate a code using multiple authy apps that matches the one the totp.generate() generates. I think the issue might be either due to me passing an invalid secretKey format/type into totp.generate(). Or the issue might me due to the configuration of the totp component(maybe using the wrong encryption type(i.e sha2)) when compared to the authy app.

Here is my code sample following the guide from: https://npm.io/package/otplib

```
const generateSecretKey = (size=16) => { 
  const val = crypto.randomBytes(size).toString('hex').slice(0, size).toUpperCase()  
  return val;
}

const generateTotp = (secret) => {
 const token = totp.generate(secret)
 return token;
}

const authChallenge = (token, secret) =>{
 const isValid = totp.check(token, secret);
 return isValid
}

let secret = generateSecretKey()
console.log("secret => " + secret)
let token = generateTotp(secret)
console.log(`generateTotp => token ${token}`)
let authChallengeResponse = authChallenge(token, secret)
```

The returned value is

[image]

It seems the package is able to generate the code, the issue is it is not the same code as the ones in the authy app. Could this be due to me providing an invalid key type?